# Reset link style to <A> containing an image inside a div

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Look, this is my test site.

http://www.securebitcr.com/test/balls.php

The problem that I am having is, that I see the link style in the flying objects, but I am resetting that in my css .

Please take a look at my code, I've been trying a lot of things and anything works for me.

Thanks,

Marco,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS?

```
.box img {
    border: 0
}
```

Comment: You did it again ! ... awesome my friend !

Comment: It seemed too easy :O In pretty much every browser, linked images have that pesky default border. Edit: I understand what you meant by "You did it again". I looked through your questions, and it seems I've now answered over half of them, lol.